# How can I get jenkins to work on a GIT tag

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a release cycle that relies on created tags to release. In example: When we tag the trunk with v1.10.3 it should release that. How can I get jenkins to see this? I can't find a way to let jenkins perform a specific job on a available tag.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard about `Branch Specifier` in the Git plugin. This link about [Jenkins and the Git Branch Selection](http://www.sourceprojects.org/jenkins-and-the-git-branch-selection) may help.